# Unable to find either renderd.py or generate_tiles.py?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, rendering

We created a Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x64 OSM tile server from packages using the excellent instructions provided by 
http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

The tile server is running well and serving tiles of Kansas USA.

We now would like to set the scale_factor for MAPNIK in order to improve the appearance of tiles on displays with high DPI.

Following various instructions, we located renderd.conf (i.e. /etc/renderd.conf) but cannot locate renderd.py or generate_tiles.py

Are either of these files included with an install using the repository ppa:kakrueger/openstreetmap?

If so, let us know where. If not, tell us if it is possible to add them, and how it might be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been rewritten with C, so now it's just `renderd`. On my ubuntu:

```
which renderd
/usr/bin/renderd
```